# Splitting a linked list into two lists and interleaving their nodes together into one linked list

Tags: java, nodes

I am attempting to split a list of nodes in two and merge the two linked lists back into a single list. For example `{"KH","4C","8C","QC","3D","7D","JD"}` becomes `{"KH","4C","8C","QC"}` `{"3D","7D","JD"}`   (if as in this case the lists   have    an odd number of nodes then the first list is   longer) and returns the list `{"KH","3D","4C","7D","8C","JD","QC"}`. Looking through my errors it seems I am not merging the lists back together properly in my if statement.

I have to use the provided node class and cannot    use static  variables,  arrays  or  Java    collections. Could you explain how I should be merging my two lists of nodes back together?

*my code*

```
public class ListShuffleExample {

public static Node<String> shuffle(Node<String> deck) {
    if(deck == null){
        return null;
    }
    int decklength = length(deck);
    if(decklength % 2 == 0){
        Node<String> first = deck;
        Node<String> second = deck;
        int halflength = decklength / 2;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < halflength; i++){
            second = second.next;
        }
        while(second.next != null){
            first.next = second;
            second = second.next;
        }

        return first;

    }
    else{
        Node<String> first = deck;
        Node<String> second = deck;
        int halflength = (decklength / 2) + 1;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < halflength; i++){
            second = second.next;
        }
        while(second.next != null){
            first.next = second;
            second = second.next;
        }

        return first;

    }

}

public static int length(Node<String> adeck){
    int length = 0;

    while(adeck.next != null){
        length++;
        adeck = adeck.next;
    }

    return length;
}
}
```

*Node class*

```
public final class Node<T> {
public final T       value;
public       Node<T> next;

public Node(T _value) {
    this( _value, null );
}
public Node(T _value, Node<T> _next) {
    value = _value;
    next  = _next;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "" + value;
}
}
```

*my test case*

```
@Test
public void testMany() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Node<String> input  = makeList( _AH, _5H, _9H, _KH, _4C, _8C, _QC, _3D, _7D, _JD, _2S, _6S, _TS );
    Node<String> actual = ListShuffleExample.shuffle( input );
//                                           _AH,      _5H,      _9H,      _KH,      _4C,      _8C,      _QC
//                                                _3D,      _7D,      _JD,      _2S,      _6S,      _TS
    for (Object expected : new Object[]{ _AH, _3D, _5H, _7D, _9H, _JD, _KH, _2S, _4C, _6S, _8C, _TS, _QC }) {
        assertEquals( "Incorrect value", expected, actual );
        actual = actual.next;
    }
    assertNull( "Incorrect result", actual );
}
```

Comment: Are you attempting to shuffle a real deck of cards? If so you should look into a real shuffling algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle is a good one) and also should probably not have a test case that tests for a specific a output after shuffling. Shuffling should be at least somewhat random.

Comment: shuffling is probably a bad choice of words really i want split the list of nodes in two and place the first node of list 2 after each node of list 1.

Comment: First of all you need to get your terminology right so that we can understand you better. You are implementing a linked list. A node is just a single element in the linked list, which apart from carrying its data (a `String`), is pointing to the next element in the list. Have you tried to debug it line by line to see how your references are changing?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: yes this  a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you are not really shuffling, but you are interleaving the two lists together. So its like when you get to decks of cards and join them into one deck, alternating them one from each deck.

The problem in your code is here:

```
  while(second.next != null){
            first.next = second;
            second = second.next;
        }
```

You are never updating the `first` reference to move to the next node, and you are never updating the `second` reference to point to the one after the first. You are always overwriting the same `first.next`.

What about:

```
 Node<String> curFirst = first;
 Node<String> curSecond = second;

 while(curFirst != null && curSecond != null)
 {
    //save the next one of the first list
    Node<String> nextFirst = curFirst.next;

    //set the next one of the first list to the first one of the second list
    curFirst.next = curSecond;

    //save the next one of the second list
    Node<String> nextSecond = curSecond.next;

    //set the next one after the inserted item to the previous next of the first list
    curSecond.next = nextFirst;

    //set the current references to the next ones
    curFirst = nextFirst;
    curSecond = nextSecond;
 }
 //once any of the pointers becomes null it means we're done because the rest of the list should be still intact
```

You might need to check for some corner cases when the list is empty, or when the list only has 1 item etc., but I leave that to you!

**UPDATE** After comments below

The length calcuation is also wrong, it will throw a `NullPointerException` if the list is empty (i.e. `aDeck` is `null`), and will return one less item if it contains any items. You should change the condition to `while(adeck != null)`.

Furthermore, don't have repeated code. Move the part where you are traversing to the `halflength` and merging the list to after the else finishes. Its the same for both when the length is even or when it is odd.

Comment: so the way I am finding the length of the original single list and splitting it is correct I am assuming?

Comment: Well you just asked about the merging and that is what I looked at primarily... I haven't tried the above code by the way, but the idea should work. I think the way you are finding the length is wrong... what if the list is empty? (You will get a `NullPointerException` in the `while` condition). What if the list has just one item? (You will get `adeck.next == null` in the first iteration, and thus `length` will remain 0 and never updated once. Reason things out and test with corner cases. I think it should be `while(adeck != null)` instead.